# kubernetes nginx upstream server as service not found

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

These are my yaml files referenced by [here (kubernetes.io/docs)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/)

[deployment gists](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/8010f989fb3f90b59fab1dd50daa872f)

And I use command `kubectl apply -f backend-deployment.yaml -f frontend-configmap.yaml -f frontend-deployment.yaml`

Backend were launched successfully, but Frontend occured error.

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "backend-service" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
#nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend-service" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
```

Even if 'backend-service' is declared, nginx couldn't recognize it.

Command `nslookup backend-service` result is:

```
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find backend-service: SERVFAIL
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the output of "kubectl get pods" and "kubectl get svc" and "kubectl get endpoints"?

Comment: @meaningqo holy....sorry, worker node is down....after reboot, i'll comment

Comment: @meaningqo result is https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/a155d9cf5f7bb03920a4dae3982a27fe

Comment: I am a bit confused by that output as the backend-service show type ClusterIP but has no clusterIp assigned. your yaml configuration file however says type nodeport for your backend service. 

i have tried to reproduce your issue on minikube, however i dont have your private images used, so i used the default nginx and mysql image for  front-/backend.

Comment: I have also changed the type of the backend service to "ClusterIP". nginx is starting up successfully. however i am not much of an nginx guy, so i dont know whether it consumes the config-map by default on the mountpoint specified in your deployment.

Comment: @meaningqo ok, i'll check clusterip.

Comment: if that doesn't solve the issue and if your images don't contain anything secret you can upload them to dockerhub, add them to your question and i can try finding a solution with the same setup as you have.

Comment: @meaningqo yes, there is no secret. i will try upload to hub.

Comment: @meaningqo use image at my answer, thank you...thank you

Comment: @01hanst, is your problem now resolved?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I couldn't solve it and went to work hhhh. I compare my yamls with @ meaningqo's yamls, there is no diff. but result is different. when deploy backend, get error : getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mysql-service. I'll check this tomorrow.

Comment: @01hanst, any progress?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak oh yes. i wrote answer. The cause was coredns in kube-system. Node.js handed over the host to access Mysql but didn't recognize it, so I thought the service's address was not managed. So I checked the log of coredns, and there was an error, and when I restarted, there was no error. Then, the backend was connected to mysql without any problems, and the frontend was able to recognize the backend-service as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten closer to the issue/solution.

First of all, you if the images in your supplied answer are correct, you are running nginx in your backend deployment and node-js server on your frontend deployment. This is a mistake.

after changing the images frontend is running (as expected) but backend pod is crashing.

However, the backend pod is successfully resolving the mysql-service to its internal clusterIp and I appear to have wrong authentication setup.

```
`> server@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
 > node backend.js
 
 (node:18) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
 (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 (node:18) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
 (node:18) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
 (node:18) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
 listening on 3000
 events.js:292
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^
 
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.100.77.32:3306
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1142:16)
     --------------------
     at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
     at Protocol.handshake (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
     at Connection.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/backend.js:58:12)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
 Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
     at Connection._handleProtocolError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
     at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at Protocol._delegateError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
     at Handshake.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:12)
     at Handshake.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at Handshake.Sequence.end (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:12)
     at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:369:14)
     at Connection._handleNetworkError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:96:8)
     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
   errno: -111,
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '10.100.77.32',
   port: 3306,
 > node backend.js
   fatal: true
 }
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node backend.js`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-21T08_46_32_833Z-debug.log`
```

if you look at the log. it says it tries to connect to 10.100.77.32:3306 and the output of kubectl get svc is the following `mysql-service      ClusterIP   10.100.77.32     <none>        3306/TCP       17m`

with the matching ip of my service.

kubectl get endpoints shows that the mysql-service has indeed found an endpoint:

```
mysql-service      ClusterIP   10.100.77.32     <none>        3306/TCP       17m
```

and here is additional log information showing that the authentication mechanism of your nodejs application appearently is not working for the mysql pod.

```
  Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:296:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/backend.js:58:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:12)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:12)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:125:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9) {
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node backend.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-21T08_55_22_133Z-debug.log
```

However, with the changes suggest at the beginning of the answer the issues around resolving the service name and communicating inside of kubernetes should be resolved.

Comment: oh...yes. It's my mistake. When i edit gist to change images source local to docker hub, the images of each other were reversed.

Comment: i updated all of gist https://gist.github.com/darknisfire. is that right?

Comment: unfortunately,  I need to get to a meeting myself now and start my daywork. 

however, I have pasted my currently applied configuration here: 
https://gist.github.com/fhochleitner/179e8f0eaa5b3820ecac9aa37878c0be so you can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

backend-deployment image : bateaux/test-nginx

frontend-deployment image : bateaux/test-node-server

When deploy backend-deployment, remove [livenessProbe, readinessProbe].

Because node.js express server use @cloudnative/health-connect To readinessProbe, so call PingCheck(worker node ip).

Comment: holy.....if remove [livenessProbe, readinessProbe], there is no upstream error. Another error appeared hhhhh. It's hopeful.

Comment: look similar to the output I got trying your setup. 

backend doesn't log anything but is up and running. 
frontend is stuck in crashloopbackoff due to getting connection refused trying to connect to mysql on 127.0.0.1:3306 
see https://gist.github.com/fhochleitner/a4d3d826ba5863b666541318e0fce258

Comment: two things for this issue: 
your mysql-service is still in state pending because you are using type LoadBalancer. This type only works in a cloud environment or when you have deployed something yourself that provisions an external loadbalancer. i suppose mysql should only be accessible from inside your cluster. can you try to also change this services type to type: ClusterIP and delete the NodePort section of the service if a port has been assigned to it.

Comment: @meaningqo I removed service type, nodePort. But error is still there.

Comment: did you change it to type: ClusterIP as well? 
it appears that your backend.js is resolving mysql-service as 127.0.0.1 which shouldn't be the case. or have you defined it as 127.0.0.1 or localhost somewhere else?

Comment: @meaningqo yes i remove type. because default type is ClusterIP. and i tried to set tpye:clusterIP, but still error. and i didn't defined. This is describe mysql-service. https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/b4690195a228c9bd05bc4b41c091d0a9

Comment: @meaningqo There is blank endpoint for 'frontend-service', is this normal?

Comment: somewhat. enpoints get registered by pods matching the labelSelector of your service. 
so one endpoint per pod that is in a readyState is expected to be associated with the service. 
because your frontend pod is failing and in a CrashLoopBackoff state, the service does not have a valid pod that it can register as ep.

Comment: @meaningqo thanks for the explanation. i understand ep - pod. i've been add port 3304 to backend-service, but still error.

Answer (score 0):

Wow....I found solution for `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mysql-service`.

I think if network can't find service, there is error in dns.

`kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns`

Result of command is [gist](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/a46ef920a66538851daff091fc398702).

So...I finally found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782064/coredns-has-problems-getting-endpoints-services-namespaces) about kubernetes coredns.

By belphegor's answer, it works restart coredns.

Although, there is new error `Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`, but i think to solve it is easier than dns error. hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh